# using json parser how to display php webservices data in UIview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i have a PHP webservices. My requirement is using PHP web services to display json data in `UIView` one by one.

The Json data is :

> "id\":\"6\",\"title\":null,\"description\":null,\"year\":\"2012\",\"date\":null}","{\"id\":\"4\",\"title\":\"
>   correct in the year 2013\",\"description\":\"*<\/font> Financial
>   system in America for this year is not indicated progress this year
>   too. More problems will creep up. \r\n*<\/font> Aggressive stage
>   of Telangaana agitation- formation of seperate Telangaana state-
>   bifurcation of state - sure indications are \r\n\r\npredicted.
>   \r\n*<\/font> The Gujarath CM - Sri Narendra Modi - Bright future
>   is indicated.  \r\n*<\/font> Still danger is indicated for
>   Indoneshia and Sumitra Islands.

i want to display these data in UIView.Before display each line of data displaying * symbol.How to retrieve and how to display in UIViewcontroller.Help me any body.Thanks in advance.
I am writing like this.but i got exception.

```
-(void)loadData

{

NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults valueForKey:@"id"];

[defaults valueForKey:@"title"];

[defaults valueForKey:@"description"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.predictions.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

urlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{

responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

[responseData setLength:0];

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{

[responseData appendData:data];

}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

if(connection==urlConnection)

{

strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",strResponse);

NSError *error;

jsonDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonDict);


NSArray *arrResults=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"id"];

NSLog(@"%@",arrResults);


arrString=[NSMutableArray array];

for(NSDictionary *dictRes in arrResults)

{

constants *con=[[constants alloc]init];

con.titl=[dictRes valueForKey:@"title"];

//  con.desc=[dictRes valueForKey:@"description"];

[arrString addObject:con];

}

[View1 reloadData];

}

}
```

Comment: can u give the correct url , i given the correct answer for u

Comment: I m not given any negative rating @user3214012

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSJSONSerialization` class for parsing JSON objects.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this framework: https://github.com/stig/json-framework and SBJsonParser class to parse the JSON script. The below code will help you parse json response:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init] ;

NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)[parser objectWithString:respString error:nil];
```

This code will convert your response string in the respString variable into an `NSDictionary`, and now you can extract each object by calling:

```
NSString* response = [dic objectForKey:@"response"];
```

Comment: thanks for your response bro.i want to display data in view like this  *  Financial system in America for this year is not indicated progress this year too. More problems will creep up                *Aggressive stage of Telangaana agitation- formation of seperate Telangaana state- bifurcation of state - sure indications are

Comment: line by line i want to display data bro.in each line before i want to display *symbol

Comment: Please provide the url to the json, that will help in providing the exact code